# Facebook Graph API Events

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-events

I want to make an application where I will add specific events to a webpage, and users will Login with Facebook into my website and can invite their friends to any events they want.

In the Graph API Event docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/event/invited it says "You cannot invite people to events via the Graph API.". However I found this https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/560/ where it says issuing a POST request to the /event/invited edge will invite the user to the event. There is also a notice on this second link that says "We're sorry, but the information in this post is over a year old and may be outdated. You can look for updated info by browsing our docs or trying a search.".

Has anyone here tried to do this before? I want to make sure it is possible before I start writing the code. Any help would be very useful.

Comment: why don´t you just try it? weird to ask if something works while it would take 5-10min for you to just try it. don´t be lazy ;)

Comment: It seems event management is removed in the new API version. I tried to post to /events/invited edge using the Graph API explorer, and it gives the same error message. And I just answered my own question!

Answer (score 1):

The blog post given in the question is dated Sept 2011. The Graph API 2.0 was introduced in April 2014. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

create_event permission was deprecated in Graph API 2.0 . Applications using v2.0 and v2.1 cannot manage Facebook events. Events and event counts (no of attending users, no of maybe users, no of declined users) only can be accessed in v2.0.

I did not try it, but it seems it is not possible. If anyone finds a way to do this, please let me know!